# Navigation bar loses alignment in small screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've implemented twitter bootstrap on my site.I want to know how to make nav-bar responsive like one on [twitter bootstrap official site](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).
There is problem with alignment in small size screens take a look at pic below.

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Studyfoyer</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="learn.php">Learn</a></li>
                <li><a href="teach.php">Teach</a></li>
                <li><a href="forum.php">Discuss</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Connect<b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contribute</a></li>

                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

CUSTOM CSS:

```
.nav{
  float:right;
}
/* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */
.navbar-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}

/* Flip around the padding for proper display in narrow viewports */
.navbar-wrapper .container {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

FYI to play with sizes[image: Problem with alignment in small screen][my_Site](http://studyfoyer.org/index.php)

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 0):

@media queries are what you are looking for. You can find many examples, one is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)